# Buscar en una cadena "valores concretos"

Tags: javascript

Buenas como podría buscar en una cadena un "valor en concreto.

Ej:

```
var texto = "hola #que tal# mi nombre es #amigo#" ;
```

Quiero conseguir la cadena entre `"# #"`
sería: que tal amigo

Comment: Deberías añadir el código de lo que has intentado, pero como pista te comento que puedes usar `.split('#')`

Comment: Yasiel, recuerda que en las preguntas ha de explicarse no solo lo que se **quiere** si no lo que se ha **intentado**. Has de mostrar qué problemas tuviste intentando resolverlo, que es con lo que nosotros podemos ayudarte. Para tareas sin intento se cierra como Demasiado amplia o No relacionado. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tienes la solucion.

```
var texto = "hola #que tal# mi nombre es #amigo#" ;

/// Split por espacios
var split = texto.split(' ');
var arr = [];

/// Por cad astring que contenga #, remplazar por nada, 
/// en caso de que haya dos, remplazar dos veces.
split.forEach(e => {
  if(e.indexOf('#') != -1){
    arr.push(e.replace('#', '').replace('#', ''))
  }

})

/// Unir con espacios
var finalstring = arr.join(' ');

console.log(finalstring);

/// que tal amigo
```